# Why does Alloy-as-Markdown search for ModuleNameg.md rather than ModuleName.md given open ModuleName?

Tags: alloy

I have a .md file containing this fragment:

````
---
title: behaviour of vehicle locking system
layout: default
description: concrete example drawn from 2019 Ford Transit users handbook
---
```alloy
module VehicleLocking

open Vehicle
//etc
````

and the analyzer searches for `Vehicleg.md` rather than `Vehicle.md`. Why?

Comment: Hmm, I get `Vehicle.ele`? When Electrum is moved to Alloy it will become '.als' again, I expect.

Comment: I'm not puzzled that when one `.md` file opens a module the analyzer looks for another `.md` file. What puzzles me is that it demands the `g` on the end of the filename.

Comment: Yeah. That does not make sense. Can you open a bug on the Electrum Github? Please include the text on the log window.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/haslab/Electrum2/issues/40